# Missing data when using Save Site as Template and uploading the template in different site collection

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are using "save site as template" option of sharepoint 2010 to save the site from one Site Collection and use that template to create a custom site in another site collection.

When the lists data huge , all the rows of the lists not copied to the new site.
Is there any setting or limitation for this feature?

Also we do not know whether the problem is with "save site as template" or new custom site creation using the saved template.

The generated template size 2 MB and the max limit set is 200 MB.
No error was thrown during the process.

Answer (score 0):

How many items do you get? The first 5000? Or does it differ from time to time?

Comment: There were 250 items in one of the list, i got only 10 of them.
tried multiple times, but the same count.

Comment: My answer should have been a comment, sorry for that. I suggest you try to import your site template as a wsp package into visual studio. By doing that you are at least able to see if all items are exported. If they are, you know the error is in the create site part.

Comment: thats cool. The generated template is having all the items in the list. Once again i am trying to upload the template and will let you know.

Comment: No Luck, still the destination is site is loaded with less records, but no error was thrown during site creation.

Comment: Is there anything in the site log files to indicate what might have failed? SharePoint logs are in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS` for SharePoint 2010.